# ES6 template literals based on template variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I try to render a ES6 template literal variable :

```
function render(template, data){
 ...
}
const template = 'resources/${id}/';
console.log(render(template, {id: 1})); // -> resources/1/
```

**Does exist a way to transform a string template with context into a formated string with ES6 template literals feature ?**

Answer (score 16):

You can not do this with simple template literals.

However, you can achieve such behaviour by wrapping your literals into functions. Thanks to ES6 features (desctructuring and arrow functions), the result code is simple

```
function render(template, data) {
  return template(data);
}
const tpl = ({ id }) => `resources/${id}/`;

console.log(render(tpl, { id: 1})); // resources/1/
```

Comment: Or even simpler:
```(({ id }) => `resources/${id}/`)({ id: 1})```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the original question. The moral of the original question is what you hold is `'resources/${id}/'` as a variable.

Comment: @QianChen why do you think so? I believe I've stated the answer quite clearly.

Comment: If the `\`resources/${id}/\`` is held in a variable which is read from network or a file, what will you do?

Comment: @QianChen I don't get. Why should I do anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

ES6 template literals can't be compiled at run time. To do this, third-party library should be used, like [`es6-template`](https://github.com/tunnckocore/es6-template).

At this point there's no real benefit in using template literal syntax, any other template engine of choice may be used instead.

Comment: is this still releavnt? i face the same issue and wonder if to use es6 literal template or not

Comment: Yes, it is. Use template engine when you need one.